# project-serum / anchor : anchor test command is not working

Tags: typescript, anchor, smartcontracts, solana

```
Cannot find module '/home/rasitha/videos/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

I'm getting above error after running anchor test command in basic-1 example in https://github.com/project-serum/anchor. Any help would be apprecicated.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you run `yarn` to install everything from `package.json`?

Comment: can you provider more information?

Comment: @JonC I ran yarn install, Even But it didn't work.

Comment: @DaveTheAl Actually I followed a youtube video example. But it ended up with this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to build the anchor/ts package

**do the following**

cd anchor/ts

yarn install

yarn build

cd ../examples/tutorials

rm -rf node_modules

yarn install

pls try this

Comment: Actually I build from the scratch following anchor documentation.
Then it worked. I followed these steps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get `anchor test` to work by installing the necessary packages globally. (*@project-serum/anchor, ts-node, and yarn*)